# Play app failing with no exception thrown

Tags: playframework-2.1

I have a play application running on a linux server. The play application handles an ajax request, the controller code that handles the request :

```
public static Result getStorageId() {

    final String host = request().username();
    logger.debug("get storage id from origin:" + host);
    Promise<Product> promiseProduct = Akka.future(new Callable<Product>() {

                @Override
                public Product call() throws Exception {
                    Partner partner = PartnerModel.getPartner(host);
                    logger.debug("Partner origin:" + partner.getHost());

                    ** Product productCase = ProductsModel.createProduct(); 

                    logger.debug("product created. id:" + productCase.getId());
                    return productCase;
                }
            });

    return async(promiseProduct
            .map(new Function<Product, Result>() {

                @Override
                public Result apply(Product product) {

                    return ok();

                }
            }));

}
```

The ProductsModel.createProduct() code is

```
public static Product createProduct(){
    logger.debug("creating new product");
    Product product = new ProductImpl();

    saveProduct(product);
    return product;
}
```

The issue is when an ajax request made the app reaches line ** and stops but there's no error indicated in the application.log file nor in the play console. The debug statement in the first line of createProduct() method is not executed. The app is still running as I can make another ajax request and see the log statement before line **.

I did try "play run" hoping that it might give more info since it runs in debug mode but no luck.

My local development copy works fine. Another thing, I had this issue before and as a desperate attempt I just create a new class "ProductTestModel" with the same functionality as ProductsModel and used it instead of ProductsModel (ie on line ** it goes Product productCase = ProductTestModel.createProduct() ) deployed it and everything worked. Now after several releases I get this problem again.

I'm using GIT to distribute the code to the server and have play compile the app there. Running play clean compile shows no errors.

So what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the root cause of my problem. It's actually a stupid thing, I forgot to include a conf file. Where the code was failing that object was using that conf file.

Talk about hours being wasted!!

Comment: How did you find this out?

Comment: By luck really. While I was double checking another config file, I noticed it was missing.